# Trimming the last 3 characters off a string based on a condition

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a Case statement that returns a different amount of zeros depending on the case selected. I need a way to, if the amount of zeros is greater than 3, trim the last 3 zeros off the string. I currently have the cases returning strings such as "0" or "000000".  In that situation, the code would turn the "000000" into "000".

I currently have:

```
If NumberOfZeros.Length > 3 Then  
    NumberOfZeros.Remove(0, NumberOfZeros.Length - 3)  
End If
```

But obviously, this doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: If anybody could refine this post, please do.
At the request of a comment, here is the CASE in question.

```
    Dim Colour As String = " "
    Colour = Cmbl3.SelectedItem

    Select Case Colour
        Case "Black"
            NumberOfZeros = "0"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.Black
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "Brown"
            NumberOfZeros = "00"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.SaddleBrown
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "Red"
            ValueOf0s = "000"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.Red
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "Orange"
            NumberOfZeros = "0000"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.Orange
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "Yellow"
            NumberOfZeros = "00000"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "Green"
            ValueOf0s = "000000"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.Green
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "Blue"
            NumberOfZeros = "0000000"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.Blue
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "Violet"
            NumberOfZeros = "00000000"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.DarkViolet
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "Grey"
            NumberOfZeros = "000000000"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.Gray
            Cmbr.Enabled = True
        Case "White"
            NumberOfZeros = "0000000000"
            lblcolour3.BackColor = Color.White
            Cmbr.Enabled = True

        Case Else
            MsgBox("You must enter a colour choice from the third option box!")

    End Select 

            If NumberOfZeros.length > 3 Then
                NumberOfZeros.Remove(0, NumberOfZeros.Length - 3)
            End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that if you posted more of the context, we could replace your entire complicated CASE statement with a simple single-line format string expression, or perhaps a mathematical calculation for an argument to the right string constructor overload. Would you mind updating the question with the full context and CASE code?

Comment: Of course! Just one second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, returning different amount of zeroes in that Case-structure sounds a bit strange, why not use different numbers or bit-flags for different conditions?

Is `NumberOfZeros.length` a typo in the SO-msg, or real code? Shouldn't it be `NumberOfZeros.Length`?

Comment: It was indeed a typo. In the code, it is .Length  
The case is necessary as it is for a specific written task in my computing course! It seems silly as I wouldn't have done it that way, either.

Comment: Hmm, you wrote that 'obviously' this didn't work. Could you explain why you concluded that it did not work? (I have a suspicion that some of the following code might be buggy...)

Comment: MBaas, when I output the NumberOfZeros variable, it made the string empty.

Comment: And you really did output the string right before and after that `if..remove`-Statement? Does the string contain blanks? Perhaps add some delimeters to the output...

Comment: Yes, sir. Removing that if statement will output the whole string; implementing it will return nothing.
May I ask what delimeters are? I've been using vb for a matter of weeks to a low standard.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting the whole thing. Now...the remove-stuff is only execute within the `ELSE`-branch of the statement. In other words, whenever a "legal" value has been `SELECT`ed, you assign any number of zeroes and do not execute the `remove`-code!

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that! That makes perfect sense. Therefore, the If statement should be after the End Select and before the End Sub?

Comment: Yes, that woule be better :)

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work which is rather frustrating but also, now, beginning to become confusing. However, now, when the If statement is implemented, the string isn't empty, which is an improvement in itself :)
Is there anyway to convert an integer to X amount of things? E.G, "NumberOfZeros = 4" and then we can use/convert that 4 into four zeros?

Comment: First: your code now has "VNumberOfZeros"??? Before replying, can you pls explain what you are trying to achieve with that NumberOfZeros then

Comment: That's strange as I didn't edit that. I'll edit it out now.
And the number of zeros relate to the tens, hundreds, thousands etc, of Ohms that a resistor has. For instance, if the colour band on the resistor is Orange, it will have 10'000 Ohms of resistance. The purpose of the code I want to implement will subtract the last three zeros and replace it with "K". Thus, changing 10'000 Ohms into 10K Ohms.
Equally, 100'000 into 100K Ohms.

Comment: MBaas, thank you very much for your help. I've managed to solve my problem! Much rep. You've been great.

Comment: Thanks Ben- glad I was able to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

A class representing a stripe will go a long way to condensing your code:

```
Public Class Stripe
    Public colour As Color
    Public value As Int64
    Public name As String
    Sub New(_colour As Color, _value As Int64, _name As String)
        colour = _colour
        value = _value
        name = _name
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return name
    End Function
End Class
```

Creating a list of this class and assigning it to the datasource property of the combobox will fill it.

```
Public stripes As New List(Of Stripe)
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    stripes.AddRange(
        {
        New Stripe(Color.Black, 1, "Black"),
        New Stripe(Color.Brown, 10, "Brown"),
        New Stripe(Color.Red, 100, "Red"),
        New Stripe(Color.Orange, 1000, "Orange"),
        New Stripe(Color.Yellow, 10000, "Yellow"),
        New Stripe(Color.Green, 100000, "Green"),
        New Stripe(Color.Blue, 1000000, "Blue"),
        New Stripe(Color.DarkViolet, 10000000, "Violet"),
        New Stripe(Color.Gray, 100000000, "Grey"),
        New Stripe(Color.White, 1000000000, "White")
        })
    cmbl3.DataSource = stripes
End Sub
```

Now getting the values from the selecteditem is a simple matter of converting it back to a stripe object:

```
Private Sub cmbl3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbl3.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selectedStripe As Stripe = DirectCast(cmbl3.SelectedItem, Stripe)
    lblcolour3.BackColor = selectedStripe.colour
    'This assumes you have a label named lblvalue3 to display the value
    If selectedStripe.value < 1000 Then
        lblvalue3.Text = selectedStripe.value.ToString
    Else
        lblvalue3.Text = (selectedStripe.value / 1000).ToString & "K"
    End If
End Sub
```

Since you will be needing code for the different bands on the resistor you code will end up much more concise.